# Numerical evaluation of Hurwitz zeta function

Tags: algorithms, numerical-methods, special-functions

Is there a way to evaluate numerically the Hurwitz zeta function

$$\zeta(s,a) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{(n+a)^{s}}$$

that is more efficient (i.e., quick and precise) than simply explicitly adding the terms one by one?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that your variables names are uncommon, I will use the standard names from [DLMF](http://dlmf.nist.gov/25.11)
$$\zeta(s,a) = \sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(n+a)^s}$$
A good numerical algorithm uses the **Euler-Maclaurin summation** ([DLMF](http://dlmf.nist.gov/25.11#iii) or 
[Wolfram](http://functions.wolfram.com/10.02.06.0020.01)) in the form
$$\zeta(s,a) = \sum\limits_{k=0}^{n}\frac{1}{(a+k)^s}
+ \frac{(a+n)^{1-s}}{s-1}
+ \sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{B_{k+1}}{(k+1)!}\: \frac{(s+k-1)_k}{(a+n)^{s+k}}$$
where $(\cdot)_k$ is the Pochhammer symbol. Using  the properties of the Bernoulli numbers $B_1=-1/2\;$ and $B_{2k+1}=0\;$ this can be rewritten as
$$\zeta(s,a) = \sum\limits_{k=0}^{n}\frac{1}{(a+k)^s}
+ \frac{(a+n)^{1-s}}{s-1} - \frac{1}{2(a+n)^{s}}
+ \sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{B_{2k}}{(2k)!}\: \frac{(s+2k-2)_{2k-1}}{(a+n)^{s+2k-1}} \cdot
$$
The upper bound of the first sum should be selected depending on your arithmetic (e.g $n=8$ or $n=9$ for double etc). The second (infinite) sum can computed by summing the terms until there is no change (i.e. the current term is smaller in magnitude than current sum).

This algorithm is efficient for the primary range $s>0, a>0:\;$
For 80-bit floating point arithmetic I get
$\zeta(2.5,0.75)\approx 2.49154238551193522\;$ with $10$ terms of the second sum, and 
$\zeta(10,0.25)\approx 1048576.10768311475\;$ you only need two terms.

For negative $s$ you can use [Bernoulli polynomials](http://dlmf.nist.gov/25.11.E14) (for $s=-1,-2\dots$) or the [reflection formula from DLMF](http://dlmf.nist.gov/25.11.E9).

---

**Edit**: The number of terms depends mainly on $s$ and $n$. Here some intermediate values from my implementation 
for 53-bit IEEE double. For the given $(s,a)\;$ pairs $n=9.\;$
s1 is the first sum from $k=0\dots n,\;$ s2 = s1 + the next two single terms,
and s2 the total sum after finishing the last sum.

```
ZetaH(10, 0.25)
s1 = 1048576.10768311471
s2 = 1048576.10768311494
s3 = 1048576.10768311494       1 term

ZetaH(5.0, 0.25)
s1 = 1024.34894710160870
s2 = 1024.34897386673833
s3 = 1024.34897452658106       6 terms

ZetaH(2.5, 0.75)
s1 = 2.47125718157242114
s2 = 2.49147059743736321
s3 = 2.49154238551193474       8 terms

ZetaH(0.75, 0.25)
s1 =  6.13122575577889695
s2 = -0.938864666031481665
s3 = -0.937591964187151961     9 terms
```

In actual implementations, you can adjust the $n$ value, and of course there are other speed-up methods: Terminate the first sum, if there are no changes, pre-compute a certain numbers of the complicated coefficients of the second sum etc.

You find a basic C implementation in the file zeta.c of the well known Cephes library http://www.moshier.net/double.zip

---

**Edit 2**: Here the data for the two sums. The first column shows n
(the upper limit of the first sum), j is the index of the second
sum, for which the convergence criterion is achieved. The second
sum is also terminated, if the terms are non-decreasing, this
is the case for n=4,5 and the last three s,a pairs, in the
table it is shown as ---.

```
        s,a=     s,a=     s,a=       s,a=
       10,0.25  5,0.25  2.5,0.75   0.75,0.25
n=4      j=7      ---      ---       ---
n=5      j=3      ---      ---       ---
n=6      j=1      j=8      j=11      j=12
n=7      j=1      j=6      j=9       j=10
n=8      j=0      j=5      j=8       j=8
n=9      j=0      j=5      j=7       j=8
n=10              j=4      j=7       j=7
n=11              j=4      j=6       j=7
n=12              j=4      j=6       j=6
n=13              j=3      j=6       j=6
n=14              j=3      j=5       j=6
n=15              j=3      j=5       j=6
n=16              j=3      j=5       j=5
n=17              j=3      j=5       j=5
n=18              j=3      j=5       j=5
n=19              j=2      j=4       j=5
n=20              j=2      j=4       j=5
n=21              j=2      j=4       j=5
n=22              j=2      j=4       j=5
n=23              j=2      j=4       j=5
n=24              j=2      j=4       j=5
n=25              j=2      j=4       j=4
n=26              j=2      j=4       j=4
```

Comment: Thanks @gammatester for the quick and detailed answer. I have implemented the algorithm in C++ using double precision. In my case, it seems that the precision of the answer I get depends mostly on the value of $n$ in the first sum (which corresponds basically to a direct evaluation of the Hurwitz zeta function). The contribution of the second sum falls rapidly to zero and seems to never be able to compensate for the truncation of the first sum. Any idea on what I may be doing wrong?

Comment: @allard: I just edited the answer to give some intermediate values (too long for a comment). What value of $n$ do you use?

Comment: Just a question: Does this formula give correct results for complex numbers too? If so, in what range?

Comment: @Anonymous Pi: DLMF lists the ranges $a>0$ and $\Re s >-1$ or $\Re s > -2n$. I would interpret this as $a$ should be a positive real. The deeper question may be the error estimate for complex $s$ (there are no error bounds in DLMF, but the situation may be similar to the Gamma function http://dlmf.nist.gov/5.11.ii)

Comment: @gammatester: Can you give a hint concerning the connection between the choice of $n$ and the involved arithmetic ?

Comment: @jerome-benoit: See Edit 2.

Comment: @gammatester, thanks.I was looking for a mathematical explanation:
any literature reference is welcome.

Comment: @jerome-benoit: As already said, there is no error term mentioned in
[DLMF](http://dlmf.nist.gov/25.11#E9). The only source I know which
comes close to an error bound, is the series representations from
http://functions.wolfram.com/10.02.06.0020.01, you will have to handle
the final integral to get a bound dependent on $n.$ ---
Another source: [Rigorous high-precision computation of the Hurwitz zeta function and its derivatives](http://fredrikj.net/math/hurwitz_zeta.html) with a pre-print at http://arxiv.org/abs/1309.2877. In Theorem 1, there is formula (12) for the remainder term.

Comment: @gammatester In Section 64:6 (Chapter 64, last chapter) in [An Atlas of Functions](http://dlmf.nist.gov/bib/S#bib2132) we can find different formulae (with a derivation sketch). I could reproduce them starting from the Euler-Maclaurin formula 2.10.1 in [DLMF](http://dlmf.nist.gov/2.10#i) and obtain the remainder. We can find easily a simplified upper bound but it contains 4 parameters (s,a,n,k): now I am looking relevant parameters. Whatever, it appears that  in [GSL](https://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/) this approach is used, and $n$ is also 10.

Comment: Would it be appropriate to differentiate this series representation in order to numerically evaluate the derivative of the zeta function?

Comment: this is still wrong, the error term diverges: (bernoulli(100) / (100!)) * (pochhammer(4+100-2, 100-1) / (6 + 12)^(4+100-1)) for k=50 is around -1.2*10^6

Answer (score 2):

The first formula given by @gammatester agrees with that given on the Wolfram site, but the second, rewritten, form seems to be in error.

The first, simple, error is that the exponent for the $(a+n)$ term in the denominator of Bernoulli series is wrong by 2 - should be $s+2k-1$, but a more involved error is in interpreting the Pochhammer symbol when summing over the even indices, $2k$.  As given, in the rewritten formula it amounts to $(s)2k+1$.  This is incorrect: consider first the Pochhammer form in the original form as $(s + k-1)k$.  This means the first factor in the Pochhammer symbol advances by one each time, and the last one by 2.  In the even sum, it should therefore be $(s + 2k-2)2k-1$.  The first term is $(s)1 =s$, the second is $(s+2)(s+3)(s+4)$, etc. The last factor is $s+4k-4$.

Numerically the quickest way to evaluate in the loop is to increment $k$ by one, two times.  $(s+k-1)k$, is advanced one step by dividing by the first factor then adding two more.

I have implemented the correct algorithm in Fortran and Mathematica (to higher than double precision), and am in agreement with @allard that the error term after the first explicit summation - i.e. with the series including Bernoulli numbers - does not decrease as expected.  The error saturates long before the series terms begin to diverge, and is not a precision issue.

Comment: Your answer/comment is correct. Unfortunately I saw it only by accident, the `@user` notification works only from comments, and I guess your reputation was not sufficient to comment on my answer. The wrong formula is from the Cephes library documentation, AFAIK the actual code is correct. I updated the formula.